# How to efficiently manage source code updation of website in Live environment and patching?

Tags: php, backup, vs-web-site-project, code-patching

I am going to start E -commerce website soon. I am new to manage live website. this website has lots of product details, product Images,source code in PHP and script files. After it will live there would be many updations, corrections and patching in code will be done. As it's an startup so i don't have any other resource to manage it. It will be manage by me only.

Here My question is what will be best method to manage source code updation and maintain logs for this to efficient traceable. should it will maintain line by line updation logs.

Answer (score 0):

use git? import your project into a git repository and figure out a deployment process. One easy option is to ssh to the production server and run git fetch checkout etc.... Be careful to deny access to your .git folder if you do so!